# c# add logic to properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have a model with two properties:

```
public class AlertRequest
{
   public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

I need to *add check* for these props

- `FromDate` : when `null` then set as `Datetime.MinValue`;
- `ToDate` :  when `null` then set as `Datetime.MaxValue`;

How to implement this in C# ?

Comment: use a property with a backing field: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: Do your properties need to return nullable types with these changes?

Comment: This is a code smell to me. If a value shouldn't be null, then don't use a nullable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the properties *manually*:

```
public class AlertRequest
{
   private DateTime? m_FromDate = DateTime.MinValue;
   private DateTime? m_ToDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

   public DateTime? FromDate { 
     get {
       return m_FromDate;
     }
     set {
       m_FromDate = value ?? DateTime.MinValue;
     } 
   }

   public DateTime? ToDate { 
     get {
       return m_ToDate;
     }
     set {
       m_ToDate = value ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
     } 
   }
}
```

Now we can put

```
AlertRequest request = new AlertRequest();

request.ToDate = null;

// 9999-12-31 (Max Date)
Console.Write(request.ToDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: I asked the OP but my suggestion would also be to initialise to those values and remove the nullable type?

Comment: @Mr. Boy: since we have to allow to assign `null`, e.g. `myAlertRequest.ToDate = null;` we have to use `DateTime?`

Comment: Surely the whole point is you can't set as null, if you try it sets those Min/Max values

Comment: Another idea could be to allow setting null, but _return_ the Min/Max values i.e. change the getters not the setters. But it seems a bit messy unless we _need_ nullable types.